# How can make a function that prints object values in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

My website has a form that allows user input. What I want to do is make it so that if the user enters a string into the form that matches one of the strings in the object, it should print the value associated with the string. I've basically got it set up like a dictionary in Python. How can a write a JavaScript function to do this?

For example: If the User enter "pila" I want it to print "Pizza". Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<h1>Welcome to the dearn translater</h1>
<body>

<p>Enter the word you want to translate:</p>

<form id="dearn" action="form_action.asp">
Dearn Word: <input type="text" name="dword"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
dearn_dictionary={
"pizza" : ["pila"],
"nally" : ["nasty"],
"nal" : ["short for nasty"],
}
</script>

</body>
</html>


</P>
```

Comment: That seems reversed. Shouldn't it be `{ "pila" : "pizza" }`?

Comment: Yeah you're right. I realized this before I posted it, but forgot to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can do this by testing if the value of your input is a key in the object, by looking for `dearn_dictionary[key] != undefined`. (you have to actually click the 'submit' button in my example, versus just hitting enter, because the code thing on SO doesn't let you actually submit forms)

```js
dearn_dictionary={
"pizza" : "pila",
"nally" : "nasty",
"nal" : "short for nasty",
};
$('#submit').on('click',function() {
  var dword = $('#dword').val();
  if (dearn_dictionary[dword] != undefined) {
    $('#out').html(dearn_dictionary[dword]);
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="dearn" action="form_action.asp">
Dearn Word: <input type="text" name="dword" id="dword"><br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>

<p id="out"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, much obliged!

Comment: @zestyxylaphone no problemo

Answer (score 1):

1. The dictionary needs to be reversed as shown below.

   ```
   dearn_dictionary={
   "pila" : "pizza",
   "nasty" : "nally",
   "short for nasty" : "nas",
   };
   ```
2. Javascript properties can be accessed by using the `Object["PropertyName"]` syntax. So you can try `dearn_dictionary["pila"]` to get the value of 'pizaa';

You can try with following code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<h1>Welcome to the dearn translater</h1>
<body>

<p>Enter the word you want to translate:</p>

<form id="dearn" action="form_action.asp">
Dearn Word: <input type="text" id="word" name="dword"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
dearn_dictionary={
"pila" : "pizza",
"nasty" : "nally",
"short for nasty" : "nas",
};

  function myFunction(){
    var textval = document.getElementById("word").value;
    alert(dearn_dictionary[textval]);
  }
    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution:

```
<form id="dearn" action="form_action.asp">
Dearn Word: <input type="text" name="dword"><br>
<input type="button" onclick=myFunc(this.form.dword.value) value="Click Me!">
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var dict = {foo: "bar", bar: "foo"}
function myFunc(val) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dict[val];
}
</script>
```

What are we doing here?

Create a form with a text field named "dword"
add an input button that calls "myFunc" with this forms dword input value as an argument.

Add an id'd element "demo" that we can write the text to.

Assign our dictionary to the variable "dict"

define the function myFunc that takes the argument val and then adds the value to the demo element which has the key val.